# Использование переменны за функцией

Tags: python, python-3.x, переменные

У меня есть примерный код:

```
def main():
    global user_id
    user_id = 1
```

Как можно использовать переменную user_id за границей функции main?

Answer (score 1):

пишите просто

```
user_id
```

а если вы её используете в другой функции, то добавьте в начале `global user_id`. Но лучше передавайте его как параметр

Вы не вызвали `main`, поэтому переменная ещё не создано и при попытке обратиться к ней у вас будет ошибка. Для избежании ошибки вызовите метод `main`

Comment: Пробовал, но выдает 
print(user_id)

NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Если вне функций, то просто брать и использовать:

```
print(user_id)
```

А если в других функциях, то точно так же, как в вашей:

```
def func():
    global user_id
    user_id = 2
```

Comment: я немного раньше :)

Comment: при print(user_id) выдает ошибку: NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined

Comment: @ZeN А функцию вы уже запускали? Если ещё нет, то переменная ещё не инициализирована. Сначала нужно запустить вашу функцию.